# Why is select2 not initializing in my example?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Why is select2 not initializing?  My code is pretty straight forward.  I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

```
**js**

const $form = $("#c8ef8fd3-cc91-4e5f-a8ed-8923418098a4.png-edit-form")
$("#c8ef8fd3-cc91-4e5f-a8ed-8923418098a4.png-tags", $form).select2({
    tags: true,
    allowClear: true,
    width: "100%",
    theme: "classic",
    debug: "true",
    placeholder: "Add one or more tags"
});


  **html**

  <form id="c8ef8fd3-cc91-4e5f-a8ed-8923418098a4.png-edit-form" action="/apps/media/batch-update" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
      <select name="thetags" id="c8ef8fd3-cc91-4e5f-a8ed-8923418098a4.png-tags" multiple>
        
          <option selected="teams">teams</option>
          <option selected="sports">sports</option>
        
      </select>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to escape the period character (`.`) within the `id` selector. See the duplicate for how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included jQuery on your page before DOM ready code?

Give something nice name of `id` instead `c8ef8fd3-cc91-4e5f-a8ed-8923418098a4.png-tags`

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // $("#c8ef8fd3-cc91-4e5f-a8ed-8923418098a4.png-tags").select2();
    $("#something_nice").select2();
});
```

Note: Skip `.` in your `id` as name. Use `-` or `_` in the value of `id`.